# Chess players and compicated positions

Tags: analysis, strategy

Who are the best chess players of the past and present who create complicated positions and emerge as winners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most famous is Tal, he had a miniature against grandmasters about twice a year.  Nakamura was a great tactical player, but he now plays more conservatively.